# How to use copy_file in boost::filesystem?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I want to copy a file from directory to another, but my program always aborts for some reasons.Has anyone done this this before could tell me what was wrong? And how could I catch exceptions was thrown by `copy_file`, I checked boost site, but I could not find any relevant information about exception.

```
path user_path( "C:\\My Folder" );
boost::filesystem::create_directory( user_path );
path file(  "C:\\Another\\file.txt" );
boost::filesystem::copy_file( file, user_path );
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to provide a path to a file name, not just the directory it resides in.

Comment: I thought that's what I did. Could you give me a brief example?

Comment: @Chan: eduffy means you have to say: `path user_path( "C:\\My Folder\\file.txt" );`