# How to copy a file from a folder to another folder

Tags: c++, file-io

How do I copy a file from one folder to another folder using C++?

Comment: Do you want to use the command `cp` or write a clone for `cp`?

Comment: i want to write a clone for cp

Comment: i don't want to execte commands. I after successful copy i want to delete the file from first folder. need help. appreciate

Comment: "I after successful copy i want to delete the file from first folder."? You mean you want to **move** the file?

Comment: @Johnsyweb sounds like another X-Y problem.    Instead of asking how to do what they actually want to do; they ask questions of how to various steps.  At least this one is a useful step for people

Answer (score 17):

With [`std::filesystem::copy_file`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_file) from C++17:

```
#include <exception>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    fs::path sourceFile = "path/to/sourceFile.ext";
    fs::path targetParent = "path/to/target";
    auto target = targetParent / sourceFile.filename(); // sourceFile.filename() returns "sourceFile.ext".

    try // If you want to avoid exception handling, then use the error code overload of the following functions.
    {
        fs::create_directories(targetParent); // Recursively create target directory if not existing.
        fs::copy_file(sourceFile, target, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) // Not using fs::filesystem_error since std::bad_alloc can throw too.  
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

I've used [`std::filesystem::path::filename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename) to retrieve the source filename without having to type it manually. However, with [`std::filesystem::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) you can omit passing the filename to the target path at all:

```
fs::copy(sourceFile, targetParent, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
```

Change the behaviour of both functions with [`std::filesystem::copy_options`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options).

Answer (score 16):

This should be the minimal code required:

```
#include <fstream>

// copy in binary mode
bool copyFile(const char *SRC, const char* DEST)
{
    std::ifstream src(SRC, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream dest(DEST, std::ios::binary);
    dest << src.rdbuf();
    return src && dest;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return copyFile(argv[1], argv[2]) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

it glosses around some potentially complicated issues: error handling, filename character encodings... but could give you a start.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use the Boost C++ libraries, take a look at [filesystem::copy_file()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_file).

Here's a previous question covering copy_file():

[How to use copy_file in boost::filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785491/how-to-use-copy-file-in-boostfilesystem)

Comment: Now copy_file is part of c++ start since c++14.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do this.

1. include c++ library `<windows.h>`
2. Use function

   ```
   CopyFile("d:/folder1/file.exe","d:/folder2/file.exe",true)
   ```
3. All Done :)

Answer (score -1):

The code below will copy all the file from one directory to another.

Its working code in C++

```
#include <windows.h>

/*
BOOL Copy(char r_szPath[1024], char r_szDir[1024])
{
char l_szTemp[2048] = {0};
sprintf(l_szTemp,"%s\%s"r_szPath,r_szDir);

if(IsDirectory(
}*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

BOOL __Copy(char r_szSrcPath[1024],char r_szDesPath[1024])
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;
char l_szTmp[1025] = {0};
memcpy(l_szTmp,r_szSrcPath,1024);


char l_szSrcPath[1025] = {0};
char l_szDesPath[1025] = {0};
memcpy(l_szSrcPath,r_szSrcPath,1024);
memcpy(l_szDesPath,r_szDesPath,1024);

char l_szNewSrcPath[1025] = {0};
char l_szNewDesPath[1025] = {0};

strcat(l_szTmp,"*");

hFind = FindFirstFile(l_szTmp, &FindFileData);
if(hFind == NULL) return FALSE;

do
{

if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
{
if(strcmp(FindFileData.cFileName,"."))
{
if(strcmp(FindFileData.cFileName,".."))
{
printf ("The Directory found is %s<BR>, FindFileData.cFileName);

sprintf(l_szNewDesPath,"%s%s\",l_szDesPath,FindFileData.cFileName);

sprintf(l_szNewSrcPath,"%s%s\",l_szSrcPath,FindFileData.cFileName);
CreateDirectory(l_szNewDesPath,NULL);
__Copy(l_szNewSrcPath,l_szNewDesPath);
}
}
}
else
{
printf ("The File found is %s<BR>, FindFileData.cFileName);
char l_szSrcFile[1025] = {0};
char l_szDesFile[1025] = {0};
sprintf(l_szDesFile,"%s%s",l_szDesPath,FindFileData.cFileName);
sprintf(l_szSrcFile,"%s%s",l_szSrcPath,FindFileData.cFileName);
BOOL l_bRet = CopyFile(l_szSrcFile,l_szDesFile,TRUE);

}


}
while(FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
FindClose(hFind);
return TRUE;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
__Copy("C:\fcdb\","E:\sandy\");
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO... to improve your post consider deleting it or addressing these issues 1. this isn't working code, you have a swarm of errors in your if statements regarding '.' and '..'..  and don't forget the typo in your include where you omitted a space.  2. you didn't answer the question at hand. You answered a question you created.  3.  the question is for C++ and Ubuntu... using windows specific stuff is not useful here 4. Please indent your code so that its readable