# C++ Copy File to Directory From Resources?

Tags: c++, file, copy

Suppose I have an external dll file that I would like to drop to a directory, how can I add said file to "resources" and how can I copy and place it in a directory?

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do is use the fstream library. [Here is a previously answered question similar to yours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125122/how-to-copy-a-file-from-a-folder-to-another-folder)

From user [CapelliC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874024/capellic):

```
#include <fstream>

// copy in binary mode
bool copyFile(const char *SRC, const char* DEST)
{
    std::ifstream src(SRC, std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream dest(DEST, std::ios::binary);
    dest << src.rdbuf();
    return src && dest;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return copyFile(argv[1], argv[2]) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Response/Edit-
No problem! To make a new directory you can use mkdir once you add the direct.h library, as followed:

```
      mkdir("c:/myfolder");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem is that the file isn't in a folder already, it's non existant. It'd have to be from the program itself.

Comment: Er, that doesn't really help me much. I want to take a file from my application itself and copy it to a directory

Comment: Hmm, could you be a little more specific with the problem? Sorry, I thought I was on the same page. :/

Comment: It's fine, I'm probably not explaining it properly. So, I have my own dll c++ project, and I have an exe project. I'd like my exe application to copy my dll project and drop it in a directory.

Comment: Cool, so the exe application needs to copy the dll project, and paste it to a directory of your choosing. Are you maybe looking for static linking?

Comment: It could be that, not 100 percent sure though. I remember that in vb.net you could have a file in "resources" and you could copy it to anywhere you like, I'd like something like that

Comment: Well I hope it is! I'm not too familiar with vb so I can't say. If not, I apologize for bringing you this wall of text. Not what I intended to do.

Comment: It's alright, thanks for your replies :) hopefully I can find a solution somewhere else